# Why is STL "empty" member function not called "isEmpty"?

Tags: c++, stl, naming-conventions, naming

Kindly check `std::vector` from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/empty/).

It says it has an `empty()` member function:

```
empty
Test whether vector is empty (public member function )
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/empty/
Signature : bool empty() const;
```

To me, empty meaning should have been to remove all elements from this container. However, it's a testing function which checks if the container is empty. 
I checked all other containers, and all use empty the same way.

Why does stl not use `isEmpty()` instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Case Style

To remain consistent with the naming convention of the C++ standard library, I would have actually baptised the member function you are referring to as **`is_empty()`** instead of `isEmpty()`. That is, following the [*snake case*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) naming convention instead of the [*camel case*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) one. We can see this convention in other member functions, e.g., `push_back()` and `pop_back()`.

---

Note that there is a member function called `clear()` that does *empty* the container. Perhaps the reason for omitting the verb (i.e., the *is* of a hypothetical `is_empty`), and therefore requiring less typing, was this separation of names for ***querying*** whether the container is empty (i.e., `empty()`) and ***emptying*** the container (i.e., `clear()`).

Otherwise, if the word "empty" would have been used instead, for both the query and the update, the verb would have been probably part of the name of the member function for querying, since both member functions have no parameters. Therefore overloading wouldn't have been possible. The member functions would have been then likely called `empty()` and `is_empty()` for emptying the container and for querying whether it is empty, respectively.

---

#### `[[nodiscard]]` attribute

In these cases where the name of a member function corresponds to both an *adjective* and a *verb* (e.g., member functions with the name `empty`, `clear` or `clean`), using the C++17's `[[nodiscard]]` attribute can be very useful to signal misbehavior.

For example, `empty()` as in `std::vector` – a member function that performs a *query*, and therefore, returns a value – can be marked  `[[nodiscard]]`, so that if the return value is not used, the compiler issues a warning. This warning signals that the programmer may have used `empty()` as if it did empty the container, but it actually queries whether the container is empty.

Note, however, that the compiler is not required to issue a warning.

Answer (score 0):

The creator of the `empty()` STL method seems to not have known, or decided not to follow, the useful naming convention that sees the names of boolean variables and functions starting with a verb. `empty()`, as you pointed out, is an ambiguous name because the word 'empty' also functions as a verb, so it can suggest an action just as much as it suggests a query, if not more. `is_empty()` would have eliminated this ambiguity by clearly indicating that the method performs a query. Unfortunately, now the STL has been standardized with this naming convention.